# Rendering two models in View yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to render two models in the actionView method, but without result. Checked some answers on previous questions and it seems my method is OK, but still do not work.

This is what a made for method view:

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $postModel = Post::find()->where(['post_id' => $id])->one();

        $currUser = BlogUser::find()->where(['id' => $postModel->user_id])->one();

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'author' => $currUser
        ]);
    }
```

and my view page:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Post */

//$this->title = $model->title;
//$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Posts', 'url' => ['index']];
//$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="post-view">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">

               <?= $model->content;
                   $author->username;
               ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It tells that the author variable is undefined but cannot realize why when i render it in the action. Will appreciate every advice! Thank you!

Comment: You want to render another file against which model?

Comment: are you sure that $currUser contain a valid model ??  .. if the query don't return a valid model you have and undefined  value

Comment: Yes, it returns a valid object author when i type the code directly in view.php. Checked it with var_dump and it seems to be right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<div class="post-view">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <?= $model->content; ?>
             <?= $author->username; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok, it is working this way! Thank you a lot! But why the other way is wrong ? Thank you again :)

Comment: <?= variable_name ?> is equivalent to <?php echo variable_name ?>. It can take only 1 variable not two.

Comment: Oh yes .. when i see it in this way <?=, i always forget that in fact this is echo. Thank you again!